# What's the meaning of `f` and `m` in PyCharm auto-completion?

Tags: python, pycharm

In the PyCharm, the auto-completion there are `f` and `m`.

What's the meaning of `f` and `m`?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Does the `f` means function?

Comment: **m**ethod, **f**ield?

Comment: if f in yello its field or in pink its function, m is method for more go here : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `f` is in yellow and in small letters, it's `field`. In pink and in capital letters it's `function`.

`m` is method

To know more take a look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html

Answer (score 8):

This is the symbol for the type. A complete list may be found in PyCharm's [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html):

```
c: class
f: field
F: function
m: method
p: parameter
P: property
v: variable
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` as function you create i.e local
`m` as method
`v` as variable
`p` as Python function that required parameters
`c` as class