# Why 'f' refer to attribute when 'm' refer to method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, attributes

does anybody know why 'f' refers to attribute when 'm' refers to method? I mean why don't use "a" to refer to attribute?

[image: File link for what I mean]

Comment: I think `f` stands for `field`. This is a generic term, because different languages use different terms.

Comment: C calls them "member variables", PHP and JavaScript call them "properties".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of \`f\` and \`m\` in PyCharm auto-completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022252/whats-the-meaning-of-f-and-m-in-pycharm-auto-completion)

Comment: Bro but in python field means something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer:

c: class

f: field

F: function

m: method

p: parameter

P: property

v: variable

These are the terms and what they mean in PyCharm

This may change if you use any other IDE or text editor

Credits: [What's the meaning of `f` and `m` in PyCharm auto-completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022252/whats-the-meaning-of-f-and-m-in-pycharm-auto-completion)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most accurate information from the official documents

[Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html#common-icons)

[image]